# IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.0 Operation Console - No runtime environment deployed in this server

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst

My new server configuration,

- Windows Server 2012 R2 64 bit
- Apache Tomcat 32 Bit
- MySQL Community Server 5.6 32 Bit
- JDK 7u76 32 bit
- JRE 7u76 32 bit
- IBM installation Manager 1.8.1 32 bit
- IBM Mobile First Platform Consumer Edition 7.0
- IBM Mobile First Studio 7.0 (from Passport advantage)

Installed everything. Operation Console loaded fine. Deployed the Project WAR file builded using the studio and deployed using the configuration tool. Restarted the Application server. Tried twice with different project war file.

The operation console always shows "No runtime environment deployed in this server".

[Server.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn23u4k9raurv5s/server.xml?dl=0)
[Tomcat Log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3t1jlissxmio081/catalina.2015-04-13.txt?dl=0)

Comment: messages.log and server.xml please...

Comment: Thanks Adar. Sent you the log file and server.xml.

Comment: Please don't send me anything. You have your question. Link it to your question.

Comment: Added the server.xml and tomcat log to the post. Thanks

Comment: @IdanAdar Where does `messages.log` file locates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the log...?

Several things from the log:

1. Unable to open the database:

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'registrationServiceFactory' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-management-service.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to open data base.

Verify your database name, username, password, URLs, etc.

2. Have you set-up the below, per the instruction in the warning...?

> SEVERE: The JVM is not properly configured to support JMX over RMI. If
>   the Tomcat instance is not running behind a firewall, the JVM property
>   com.sun.management.jmxremote.port must be defined (for example by
>   augmenting the CATALINA_OPTS variable in the setenv.bat script).
>   Otherwise, if the Tomcat instance is running behind a firewall, you
>   must define the "ibm.worklight.admin.rmi.registryPort" and
>   "ibm.worklight.admin.rmi.serverPort" JNDI properties to the values
>   reflecting the port numbers used to configure the JMX Remote Lifecycle
>   Listener.

3. Your server is out of memory.

> WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization -
>   cancelling refresh attempt
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'dataAccessService' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/Worklight/worklight/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/integration.xml]:
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'adapterManager' while setting bean
>   property 'adapterManager'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'adapterManager' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%207.0/Worklight/worklight/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/integration.xml]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [com.worklight.integration.services.impl.AdapterManagerImpl]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Follow possible solutions: http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space/

Comment: Thanks Adar, I tried using ant task to deploy the WAR file and find out the DB connectivity issue. now ant task database worked fine. Regarding item 2 and 3, will try and post you.. Thanks Again Adar.